# Is there a way to compute if some elements of an array sums up to a given target without bruteforce

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've recently implemented 2sum and 3sum in leetcode and been wondering if it's possible to find if elements can sum up to a given target without bruteforce.

Comment: Yes, if sum is not too large (using dynamic programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking if the ["subset sum problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) has a non-bruteforce solution. It's not really clear what is and what isn't a bruteforce solution, but NP complete programs (which subset sum is) have no known way to solve them in polynomial time in the worst case, but there are very sophisticated approaches to solving them that work efficiently some of the time.

The wikipedia page has good details about solving the subset sum (either approximately or exactly), and links for further reading.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

At its most general, depending on your precise definition of "brute force", this is an open problem in computer science; nobody knows. There are some algorithms that are often fast in practice, but whether there's a fundamentally fast algorithm or not, that's an active area of research

Look up "subset sum problem" and "NP-complete"